# Perl: Quickly find object in list of objects - looking for a fitting datastructure

Tags: perl, mouse

I am developing a program to sync users between to different LDAP Servers. I have two types of user groups: Master-Groups and Target-Groups (those are predefined in a config-file. There can be multiple Master and Targets per Group definition).
Users in Master-Groups missing in the Target-Groups shall be added to the Targets, Users in Target-Groups missing in Master-Groups shall be removed from the Targets.

The Users in those Groups are Objects themselves. My problem is as follows:

I loop through my availiable master groups and have to perform a quick lookup wheter a user is already part of a target-group. I am struggeling to pick the right datastructure to solve this problem. I tried using a hash, but quickly realized that hash-keys are stringyfied, so I cannot perform

```
if ( exists( $master_members->{$target_user_object} ) )
```

When using an array for storing the objects, everytime I have to check if a user object exists, I have to loop through the whole array which essentially kills performance.

How do I perfom a lookup if a specific object exists in a list of objects?

Kind Regards,
Yulivee

Comment: Do you have any field that can identify object ?  If yes, you could use this field as hash-key in hash. Example:  $master_members->{$target_user_object->ID} .

Comment: Why did you tag this with _mouse_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that hash keys are stringified. You cannot use objects as keys. But a hash is the right data structure.

Instead of just letting Perl stringify your references, build your own serializer. That could be as simple as using the `cn`. Or a concatenation of all the fields of the object. Make a sub, put that in there, call that sub within your `exist`.

```
... if exists $master_members->{ my_serializer($target_user_object) };
```